# Swiftui button style change

Tags: button, swiftui, struct, uikit

I have a button in Swiftui. When the button is clicked, the button goes into progress.

```
private struct Button1: View {
    @State var isLoading = false

    var body: some View {
            Button("Hello") {
                isLoading.toggle()
            }
            .buttonStyle(ProgressButtonStyle(isLoading: $isLoading))
    }
}
```

I created a custom button style for the button's progress.

```
truct ProgressButtonStyle: PrimitiveButtonStyle {
    @Binding var isLoading: Bool
    @Environment(\.isEnabled) var isEnabled

    func makeBody(configuration: PrimitiveButtonStyleConfiguration) -> some View {
        Button(action: { dispatchTrigger(configuration) }) {
            configuration
                .label
                .opacity(contentOpacity)
        }
        .buttonStyle(.base)
        .overlay(progressViewOverlay())
    }

    @ViewBuilder func progressViewOverlay() -> some View {
        isLoading ? ProgressView().tint(progressTintColor) : nil
    }

    var progressTintColor: Color {
        if isEnabled {
            return .white
        } else {
            return Color(.tertiaryLabel)
        }
    }

    var contentOpacity: Double {
        isLoading ? 0.0 : 1.0
    }

    private func dispatchTrigger(_ configuration: Configuration) {
        guard !isLoading else { return }
        configuration.trigger()
    }
}
```

When I control the appearance of the button with another button, there is no problem. But when I check in the same button, the text of the button disappears late. How can I solve this problem?
I have added videos of this situation.

[image: Control with another button - must be]

Problem
[image: Same button]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looked like an animation effect was being applied. The fix is to make sure the animation is nil using a transaction modifier as in button style makeBody function. This is working for me, and the text transitions immediately using iphone. On MacOS there does not seem to be an animation and so works with or without. The previous modifier .animation(nil) has been deprecated in ios15.

```
    func makeBody(configuration: PrimitiveButtonStyleConfiguration) -> some View {
    Button(action: { dispatchTrigger(configuration) }) {
        configuration
            .label
            .opacity(contentOpacity)
            .transaction({ transaction in // Transition modifier here.....
                transaction.animation = nil
            })
    }
    
    .overlay(progressViewOverlay())
    .buttonStyle(.bordered)
}
```

Some more information and credit to: https://www.avanderlee.com/swiftui/disable-animations-transactions/